# Complex integration along a line

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]My attempt: If I take integration along x-axis or y-axis and limits x=0 to x=1 along x-axis and y=0 to y=1 along y-axis then I'm not found any of the four options. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

*Of course* you don't get any of the answers if you don't integrate along the given path! Take $\gamma(t)=t+ti$ ($t\in[0,1]$). You are supposed to compute$$\int_0^1f\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr)\gamma'(t)\,\mathrm dt,$$with $f(x+yi)=x-y+ix^2$. Can you take it from here? (BTW, yes, the answer is (D).)

Comment: Your answer is good and clear but I'm not able to find f(z(t)) from f(x+it)=x-y+ix^2

Comment: Since $f\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr)=it^2$ and $\gamma'(t)=1+i$, what is missing?

Comment: I find my mistake. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Your answer is very useful to me sir.

Comment: Then please mark it as the accepted one.